# Issues running cog on system built with buildroot

Tags: buildroot

I'm new to buildroot and building customized images, so please bare with me.
I'm trying to setup a customized linux image with a tiny footprint that boots up (quickly), opens up a browser (e.g. cog) and displays local html files with javascript in fullscreen.
I was told that cog might be the right browser and right way to go. The system it's running on is a Raspberry PI 4.

I was able to get an image created that is running X11 and with cog installed. I can start cog and see in the terminal that it is successfully loading the webpage, however, I can't get the browser window to show. With my limited knowledge of X11, I was under the impression that I don't need a window manager installed if I only run one application, so I opted to skip window managers. I also installed Xterm for testing, and it runs just fine.

It would be even nicer if there was a way to get cog to run w/o X11 just in the framebuffer, but for now I'd be happy to see a browser screen somewhere. I was trying to find some guidance on how to properly install cog with buildroot, but so far I came up empty. Since the app is apparently running and only the display of the browser isn't working properly, I hope that I am close enough to a solution, but I would appreciate any pointers people can give me.

I am happy to share any logs,conf files and so on, but I'm not sure what would be helpful and didn't wanna start pasting random conf files in here, so please ask, and I'll provide.

Thanks!